# How to collect paginated resuls in scala

Tags: scala, pagination

I am trying to collect paginated results by trying to do the following logic in Scala and failed pathetically:

```
def python_version():
    cursor 
    books, cursor = fetch_results()
    while (cursor!=null) {
        new_books = fetch_results(cursor)
        books = books + new_books
    }
    return books


def fetch_results(cursor=None):
    #do some fetchings...
    return books, next_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using a recursive function, which avoids mutable values:

```
def fetchResults(c: Option[Cursor]=None): (List[Book], Option[Cursor]) = ...

def fetchAllResults(): List[Book] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(cursor: Option[Cursor], res: List[Book]): List[Book] = {
    val (books, newCursor) = fetchResults(cursor)
    val newBooks = res ::: books

    newCursor match {
      case Some(_) =>
        loop(newCursor, newBooks)
      case None =>
        newBooks
    }
  }

  loop(None, Nil)
}
```

This is a fairly standard pattern for recursive functions in Scala where the actual recursion is done in an internal function. The result of the previous iteration is passed down to the next iteration and then returned from the function. This means that `loop` is a tail-recursive function and can be optimised by the compiler into a `while` loop. (The `@tailrec` annotation tells the compiler to warn if this is not actually tail-recursive)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
 Iterator.iterate(fetch_results()) { 
   case (_, None) => (Nil, None)
   case (books, cursor) => fetch_results(cursor)
 }.map(_._1).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.toList`
```

`.iterate` takes the first parameter to be the initial element of the iterator, and the second one is a function, that, given previous element, computes the next one. 
So, this creates an iterator of tuples `(Seq[Book], Cursor)`, starting with the initial return of `fetch_results`, and then keeps fetching more results, and accumulating them, until the `nextCursor` is `None` (I used `None` instead of null, because nulls are evil, and shouldn't really be used in a normal language, like scala, that provides enough facilities to avoid them).

Then `.map(_._1)` discards the cursors (don't need them any more), so we now have an iterator of pages, `.takeWhile` truncates the iterator at the first
page that is empty,   then `.flatten` concatenates all inner `Seq`s together, and finally `toList` materializes all the elements, and returns the entire list of books.